# ImageView width not matching parent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to have 3 sections under each others using `LinearLayout` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ImageEditing">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adViewOfEditing"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageEditView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:background="#123456"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/qa_gallery" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/zoom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/qa_camera" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/erase"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/qa_trash" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/crop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/qa_view_post" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/undo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/qa_reply_comment" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

all seems to be fine , but the `Image` of the middle section , it's not matching the parent size, it has gaps at left&right, where the other sections are fine! , what am doing wrong here?

Edit: Screenshot [image]

Comment: Can you post any screenshot ?

Comment: can you try fill_parent for width attribute of imageview

Comment: I see you are adding `android:layout_weight="1"` to your second `LinearLayout` but you are not specifying `android:weightSum` on its parent. You can also try to add negative `margin` on both sides (kinda "dirty" way) to get more info about your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`

This is what eventually fixed it properly for me. You don't need scaleType.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your layout and everything is working perfect :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="#343434"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageEditView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:background="#654321"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="#123456"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/common_ic_googleplayservices" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/zoom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/common_ic_googleplayservices"  />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/erase"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/common_ic_googleplayservices"  />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/crop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/common_ic_googleplayservices"  />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/undo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/common_ic_googleplayservices"  />

</LinearLayout>
```

And screenshot :[image: sample screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problems too but

**Try to use**

```
android:background="";
```

instead of

```
android:src="";
```

Comment: Scale Type is proper way to do this

Comment: Yeah, i made use of all forms of scaleType but it's still showed some useless margins until I made use background instead